# Android studio is unable to execute drawable in activity_main

Tags: xml, android-layout

drawable code[I created a drawable file i.e.,round_button.xml and created a customized shaped for button but when I am using it in the activity_main.xml its showing the default shape of rectangle.
Here is the code of drawable file that I created
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:endColor="@color/purple_700"
        android:angle="270" />
    <size
        android:height="120dp"
        android:width="120dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#0f" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

</shape>`]
```

[2]

[this is the screen shot of both drawable and activity files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s85XC.png)

Comment: I checked the code, it's working fine .

Answer (score 0):

MaterialButton ignored `android:background` attribute until release 1.2.0-alpha06 of MDC-Android.

So, if you are using version 1.2.0-alpha05 or lower simply upgrade it to version 1.2.0-alpha06 or higher. That will solve your problem.

And add this line in your button's code to remove the blue tint : `app:backgroundTint="@null"`

Suggestion : Remove the corner attribute from your drawable. Oval shape does not need corners attribute, just make sure the height and width is equal to form a circle.